# how can I make postman document example using https

Tags: postman

right now all the example are using http://,
and I want it to be https://
appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a certificate and use it. Below are the steps.

1. Click the wrench icon on the right side of the header toolbar, choose **Settings**, and select the **Certificates** tab
2. Click the **Add Certificate** link
3. In the Host field, enter the **domain** (without protocol) of the request URL for which you want to use the certificate
4. You can also specify a custom port to associate with this domain in the Port field. This is optional. (443 will be used if not mentioned)
5. Choose your client certificate file in the CRT file field. Currently, we only support the CRT format.
6. Choose your client certificate key file in the KEY file field
7. If you used a passphrase while generating the client certificate, you’ll need to supply the passphrase in the Passphrase field.

Once your certificate is added, it should appear in the client certificates list. You should not have multiple certificates set for the same domain. If you have multiple ones set, only the last one added will be used. And this [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates) may help you for the same.

Comment: sorry, I just followup you step, but the documents still seems using http? Can I just  use the document which postman generate using 'https', I am not actually calling it.

Comment: Does the host support HTTPS?

Comment: I mean does your application deployed on HTTPs enabled host?